# Jupyter Print column details as html Ipython

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am running a code and need to print the details in Jupyter notebook with Ipython as HTML.

CSV Complexity dataframe has below values, I need to print the count of this each

```
Complexity

    Simple
    Complex
    Medium
```

Code I am using as below, need to know how I can capture the count from from dataframe and print as below.

```
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv", usecols=['Complexity'])
simp = df['Simple'].value_counts()
med = df['Medium'].value_counts()
comp = df['Complex'].value_counts()
html_code ="""
<html>
  <head>
    <h2>Themes Complexity is as below</h2>
    Simple Themes: {}<br>
    Medium Themes: {}<br>
    Complex Themes: {}<br>
  </head>
</html>""".format(simp,med,comp)

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(html_code)
```

I need to print the count of simple themes, medium themes and complex themes.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Worked Thank you

```
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv", usecols=['Complexity'])
simp = df.Test2.value_counts().Simple
med = df.Test2.value_counts().Medium
comp = df.Test2.value_counts().Complex
html_code ="""
<html>
  <head>
    <h2>Themes Complexity is as below</h2>
    Simple Themes: {}<br>
    Medium Themes: {}<br>
    Complex Themes: {}<br>
  </head>
</html>""".format(simp,med,comp)

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(html_code)
```